# Video not being displayed on tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I'm trying to display a video on a tkinter GUI. For some reason, the video is not getting displayed on the screen. Can anybody help me? I'm new to opencv and tkinter so please keep it simple.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import cv2 
    
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Video!")
    
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
    width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    def get_frame():
        ret,frame = vid.read()
        if ret :
            return(ret,cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        else :
            return(ret,None)
    def update():
        ret,frame = get_frame()
        if ret :
            img = Image.fromarray(frame)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = photo, anchor = NW)
        root.after(delay,update)
    
    canvas = Canvas(root, width = width, height = height)
    canvas.pack()
    delay = 15
    update()
    vid.release()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Here is a solution with py_vlc, it could help you out or even fit to your needs: http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/tkvlc.py;h=55314cab09948fc2b7c84f14a76c6d1a7cbba127;hb=HEAD

Comment: First you should not call `vid.release()` after calling `update()`.  Second you need to keep a reference of the image if the image is a local variable inside a function (this issue has been answered several times).

Comment: Just guessing: do not release the video source, before even entering the event loop (i.e. put `vid.release()` after `root.mainloop()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. They were very helpful. I fixed the code by referencing the image
and releasing the video source after calling `root.mainloop()`. Here is the new code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2 

root = Tk()
root.title("Video!")

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
def get_frame():
    ret,frame = vid.read()
    if ret :
        return(ret,cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    else :
        return(ret,None)
def update():
    ret,frame = get_frame()
    if ret :
        img = Image.fromarray(frame)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = photo, anchor = NW)
        canvas.image=photo
    root.after(delay,update)

canvas = Canvas(root, width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()
delay = 15
update()
root.mainloop()
vid.release()
```